# Adding values to MySQL

Tags: php, html

I am trying to test writing to MySQL database before putting all of the content of a registration form in a database but this something is wrong. Could someone review my PHP code to see where I am going wrong.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="testingPHP.php" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="Name"><br>
            Age: <input type="text" name="Age"><br>
            Gender: <select name="Gender">
                <option value=" "> </option>
                <option value="Boy">Boy</option>
                <option value="Girl">Girl</option>    
            </select><br>
            <input type ="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
$Name = $_.POST['Name'];
$Age = $_.POST['Age'];
$Gender = $_.POST['Gender'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "testing";
$password = "testing1";
$db = "tesingdb";

$conn new mysql($sername, $username, $password, $db);

$sql = "insert into testingtable (name,age,gender)
values('$Name','$Age','$Gender')"

$conn->close();
```

Comment: `$_.POST` should be `$_POST`

Comment: `$conn new mysql($sername, $username, $password, $db);` missing `=` sign. the `mysql` API is deprecated since php 5 and was removed in php 7. Don't use it anymore.

Comment: Just read the error messages, they help a lot.

Comment: $servername has the value and you are using $sername to establish the connection. It's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the changes.

- Removed `testingPHP.php` from `<form action="testingPHP.php" ...>`
- `$_.POST` to `$_POST`
- `$conn = new mysqli(....)` instead of `$conn new mysql(....)`
- Added `$conn->query($sql);`
- Spelling mistake `$servername`

**Rest of the code**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="Name"><br>
    Age: <input type="text" name="Age"><br>
    Gender: <select name="Gender">
      <option value=" "> </option>
      <option value="Boy">Boy</option>
      <option value="Girl">Girl</option>    
    </select><br>
    <input type ="submit">
</form>





<?php

$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Age = $_POST['Age'];
$Gender = $_POST['Gender'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "testing";
$password = "testing1";
$db = "tesingdb";

$conn  = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

$sql = "insert into testingtable (name,age,gender) values('$Name','$Age','$Gender')";
$conn->query($sql);

$conn->close();

?>
```